# Mysql Search Query using like in other way

Tags: php, mysql

My Question is When ever user type a keyword to search first check the spelling mistake and slimier type of word.

For example i am searching 
- "Stock" - by using like operator we can do this but i want to search for "stock" as well if spelling mistake an occur then...
example - user type stock to "stk" or "Stck" or "stok" or "tok" etc.

I want the query in a way that if user enter the keyword it will search with there spelling mistake as well.

Please Suggest...

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to explicitly provide all alternate spellings.  So, it would be something like:

```
SELECT myt.*
FROM my_table myt
WHERE
       myt.keyword LIKE '%stock%'
    OR myt.keyword LIKE '%stk%'
    OR myt.keyword LIKE '%stck%'
```

There's no magical way of just searching for misspelled words.  Computers generally have no idea what the difference is between correct and incorrect spelling.  You have to tell them what to look for.

Comment: Can we write php code if we write "Stock" then it will gives slimier type of words dynamically.